# Zend framework 2 module name routing issue

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a problem with module routing. I have 2 modules, Application and Admin. Each modules have indexAction as default action:

localhost/ --> Application/index

localhost/admin/ -> Admin/index

Admin/index works only with localhost/admin/index/

This problem happens when a module name starts with the letter "A". If I rename Admin to "Cars", localhost/cars/ works correctly!

**the error is:**

```
A 404 error occurred
The requested controller was unable to dispatch the request.
Controller:
Application\Controller\Application
No Exception available
```

This is module.config.php inside Application module:

```
<?php
return array(
    'router' => array(
         'routes' => array(
             'Application' => array(
                 'type'    => 'Segment',
                 'options' => array(
                     'route'    => '[/][:action/]',
                     'constraints' => array(
                         'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',                         
                     ),
                     'defaults' => array(
                         'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Application',
                         'action'     => 'index',
                     ),
                 ),
             ),
         ),
     ),
   'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Application' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController'
        ),
    ),

     'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'Application/Application/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/Application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),  
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'Application' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
?>
```

this is module.config.php inside Admin module:

```
    <?php
return array(
    'router' => array(
         'routes' => array(
             'Admin' => array(
                 'type'    => 'Segment',
                 'options' => array(
                     'route'    => '/admin/[:action/]',
                     'constraints' => array(
                         'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                     ),
                     'defaults' => array(
                         'controller' => 'Admin\Controller\AdminController',
                         'action' => 'index'
                     ),
                 ),
             ),
         ),
     ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Admin\Controller\AdminController' => 'Admin\Controller\AdminController'
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'template_path_stack'      => array(
            'Admin' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ), 
);
?>
```

IndexController.php

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function indexAction(){

    }
}
```

AdminController.php

```
namespace Admin\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class AdminController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function indexAction()
    {}
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What sort of error messages are you encountering?

Comment: The request `/admin/` matches both your Application and Admin routes. To fix your problem you need to remove this ambiguity.

Comment: A 404 error occurred
The requested controller was unable to dispatch the request.
Controller:
Application\Controller\Application
No Exception available

Comment: How to fix it? @tim fountain

Comment: Do you have an `indexAction` method inside this controller?

Comment: Yes, I have indexAction method inside both controllers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First your error `The requested controller was unable to dispatch the request.` only occures when the router can't dispatch the request to its defined action. So please verify that your controller are correct and the actions are present and callable.

As allready pointed out your `/admin/` route will point to two configured endpoints. This is not a problem in the first place when the admin route would be defined before the application route in the config.

So your route `/admin/` route would never be routed to your `AdminController` as the other dynamic route would be matched first.

To get you expected result use the `priority` setting in your route, to make sure your `Admin` route will be matched before your `Application` route.

```
'router' => array(
     'routes' => array(
         'Admin' => array(
             'priority' => 100,
             'type'    => 'Segment',
             'options' => array(
                 'route'    => '/admin/[:action/]',
                 'constraints' => array(
                     'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                 ),
                 'defaults' => array(
                     'controller' => 'Admin\Controller\AdminController',
                     'action' => 'index'
                 ),
             ),
         ),
     ),
 ),
```

---

Beside your question, don't end php scripts with `?>` as this could lead to bugs when a whitespace is after the end tag.